# VM not restarting automatically when installed with kickstart with --noautoconsole option

Tags: shell, virtual-machine, centos7, virtualization, kvm

I created a Centos 7.3 VM using kickstart using the following command:

```
virt-install --name=vm1 --disk path=vm1.img,size=20 --vcpus=2 --ram=10240 --os-type=linux --os-variant=rhel7.0 --network bridge=br0 --graphics none --location=http://<IP>/centos7.3 -x "ks=http://<IP>/centos73vm-ks.cfg append ip=<VM IP> netmask=255.255.252.0 gateway=<gw> bootproto=static console=ttyS0"
```

This works fine. VM is created, rebooted automatically and the node is usable. However, the problem with this is that I cannot use it to automate since I don't get the control back. To do that, I added the `--noautoconsole` options of the `virt-install` command at the end of the above command.

After doing so, VM is installed, but after reboot it does not come up automatically. It remains in `shut off` state. I need to start it manually. There are no errors on logging to the console. May someone give any leads on how to fix this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add --wait=-1 so that virt-install waits for the installation to complete before exiting. The vm will then automatically start when the installation completes.

Answer (score 1):

this sure sounds like an [issue that was covered on the RedHat customer portal](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/41976). I'm not sure if that requires a paid license but your company (or you) might have one already?

-- Jonas

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. The solution mentioned here is to add the --wait=-1 option to the `virt-install` command. Though I find it odd, that I have to wait for the entire length of the installation to get the control back, but still something is better than nothing. Thanks again.